# Why does VBScript say "Invalid Character" when using ExecuteGlobal to import a .vbs function library file?

Tags: character-encoding, vbscript, import, importerror, invalid-characters

I am encountering a "Invalid Character" error in my VBscript! In particular, within this block of code:

```
'*******************************************************************
'Import Code
'by Cheyne Wallace
'November 2008

'When using only VBscript (not QTP), this code will import any function library passed into it.
'Copy this function into a file, then use it to bring in various other function libraries.
'Usage:
'   Import "Library.vbs"

Sub Import(strFile)
    Dim objFSO : Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim wss : Set wss = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    strFile = wss.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(strFile)
    strFile = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(strFile)
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFile, 1)
    ExecuteGlobal objFile.ReadAll
    objFile.Close : Set objFSO = nothing
    Set wss = Nothing
End Sub
```

The error states "`Microsoft VBScript compilation error. Invalid Character. Code: 800A0408`" on Char: 2, Line 206 which is the very first letter on `ExecuteGlobal objFile.ReadAll` (character 1 is a tab).

I have typed and retyped the line, as well as the surrounding line breaks. Still, it keeps saying 'Invalid character'. What is going on??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem was not with `ExecuteGlobal`, but instead with the .vbs file I was attempting to import. The file I was importing was not in ANSI encoding. If VBScript has a problem with the file you are importing, it will report the error at the character and line for the beginning of `ExecuteGlobal` (which admittedly causes confusion).

Open the file you are attempting to import, convert it to ANSI and everything should work.

Answer (score 3):

FYI for those with the same problem in the future, to fix this:

1. Open the .vbs in notepad
2. Go to file and "save as"
3. Right under the file name box, you will see a drop down menu for encoding. Choose ANSI.

Answer (score 0):

Change in your code from:

```
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFile, 1)
ExecuteGlobal objFile.ReadAll
```

to

```
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFile, 1, False, -2)
ExecuteGlobal objFile.ReadAll
```

The last parameter in `OpenTextFile` function is `TristateUseDefault = -2` (Open the file using the system default.)